# Why does this function causes a "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been trying to figure this out for days now, The app.js returns a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" after I logged "Debug: 3". I am new to Javascript, so I'm not sure if I'm creating functions that call themselves in a loop or something. Here is the function that is run and causes an error.

```
function sendNewUserPackage(node) {
    console.log("Debug: 00");///////////////////////////////
    for (var i in SOCKET_LIST) {
        console.log("Debug: 01");///////////////////////////////
        var s = SOCKET_LIST[i];
        if (node === 1) {
            for (var n in Node1.NODE_PLAYERS) {
                console.log("Debug: 02");///////////////////////////////
                var pl = Node1.NODE_PLAYERS[n];
                if (s.id === pl.id) {
                    console.log("Debug: 03");///////////////////////////////Code never reaches Debug: 5 at the end of the function
                    s.emit('newUserPackage', Node1.NODE_PLAYERS);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (node === 2) {
            console.log("Debug: 04");///////////////////////////////
            for (var n in Node2.NODE_PLAYERS) {
                var pl = Node2.NODE_PLAYERS[n];
                if (s.id === pl.id) {
                    s.emit('newUserPackage', Node2.NODE_PLAYERS);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (node === 3) {
            for (var n in Node3.NODE_PLAYERS) {
                var pl = Node3.NODE_PLAYERS[n];
                if (s.id === pl.id) {
                    s.emit('newUserPackage', Node3.NODE_PLAYERS);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Debug: 05");///////////////////////////////
}

function sendClientMessage(socket, message) {
    socket.emit('message', message);
}
```

Here is how sendNewUserPackage() is called:

```
socket.on('loginAttempt', function(data) {
    //Check credentials with database...
    try {
        console.log("Debug: 1");///////////////////////////////
        Database.checkAccount(data.username, data.password, function(error, result) {
            console.log("Debug: 2");///////////////////////////////
            if (result === undefined) {
                socket.emit('loginMessage', {status:false});
                return;
            }
            if (result.length > 0) {
                socket.id = Math.random();
                SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

                var player = new Player(socket.id, result[0].Username, result[0].Rank, result[0].Points);
                player.socket = socket;
                PLAYER_LIST[socket.id] = player;
                console.log("Debug: 3");///////////////////////////////
                var nodeNumber = selectGameNode();
                console.log("Debug: 4");///////////////////////////////
                if (nodeNumber === 1) {
                    Node1.addPlayer(player);
                    console.log("Debug: 98");///////////////////////////////
                } else if (nodeNumber === 2) {
                    Node2.addPlayer(player);
                    console.log("Debug: 99");///////////////////////////////
                } else if (nodeNumber === 3) {
                    Node3.addPlayer(player);
                    console.log("Debug: 100");///////////////////////////////
                } else {
                    console.log("Debug: 5");///////////////////////////////
                    player.node = 0;
                    socket.emit('loginMessage', {status:true});
                    sendClientMessage(player.socket, 'Whoops! Looks like all games are full! Try again later!')
                    return;
                }
                console.log("Debug: 6");///////////////////////////////
                socket.emit('loginMessage', {status:true});
                sendNewUserPackage(player.node);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Debug: 7");///////////////////////////////
            socket.emit('loginMessage', {status:false});
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

What confuses me about it is that each "Debug: num" that is called only shows up once in the console. So I think that means neither function is called more than once. Could something else be causing it?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `sendNewUserPackage` used like `socket.on('newUserPage', sendNewUserPackage)` somewhere? Where is `sendNewUserPackage()` called?

Comment: if raising `newUserPackage` calls `sendNewUserPackage`, then...

Comment: I have updated the question to show where, and how it is called.

Comment: the event callback is being called over and over, probably cuz of your emit ... you need to fix that